# Method, with a foreach loop in a mini game

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I'm making a mini game that depends on different methods (that is the assignment).

In the game there are 3 piles of sticks with 5 sticks in each. I'm trying to make a method that prints the stacks of sticks.

I have made an array with `int[] sticks = new int[] = {5, 5, ,5};` (3 stacks of 5).

I want to make it visual in the console so the player can see amount of sticks etc.

If I use a method like this can I change the value in the array as they play or do I need to make another method and put it in this one?

```cs
static void Stickor(int[] array)
{
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" | ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"can i like change the value in the array as they play"* - Yes, you can change the values in your variables all you like.  Have you tried?  What didn't work?

Comment: When i run the method i get 12 sticks instead of 15, so the number is not correct. And i cant understand why. I got an array with 5, 5, 5 with the index 0 to 2. Any ide how to?

Comment: The value of `5` isn't used anywhere in the code.  The inner loop is looping from `0` to `array.Length`.  If the array has three `5`s in it then `array.Length` is `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Lists you will find it easier.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stacks = new List<int>() {5, 5, 5};
        PrintStacks(stacks);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        stacks[0] = 2;      
        PrintStacks(stacks);
        Console.WriteLine();
                
        stacks[1] = 10;     
        PrintStacks(stacks);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    static void PrintStacks(List<int> stacks)
    {
        foreach (var totalSticks in stacks)
        {
            Console.Write(totalSticks + ": ");
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSticks; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5:  |  |  |  |  | 
5:  |  |  |  |  | 
5:  |  |  |  |  | 

2:  |  | 
5:  |  |  |  |  | 
5:  |  |  |  |  | 

2:  |  | 
10:  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
5:  |  |  |  |  |
```

FYI, I changed the for loop in two ways:

- <= to < (arrays/lists are 0 indexed, so less than or equal to would
  end up looping once more than needed, because 0 is counted).
- array.Length was changed to the value of the enumerated item in the foreach loop (totalSticks). You would need to do this even if using arrays as that is what contains the amount of sticks. array.Length will always return 3 in your example, because that is the total amount of stacks, not sticks.

Lists work pretty much the same way as arrays, in that you can access them by indices as shown above (stacks[0], stacks[1], etc.).

It gives another benefit of being able to add or remove extra items without redefining the array, using stacks.Add(amountOfSticks), etc.

If you want to use arrays, basically the same code will still work. If you want to modify the amount of sticks in the array, just use `array[x] = newAmountOfSticks;`:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stacks = new int[3] {5, 5, 5};
        PrintStacks(stacks);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        stacks[0] = 2;      
        PrintStacks(stacks);
        Console.WriteLine();
                
        stacks[1] = 10;     
        PrintStacks(stacks);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        
    }
    static void PrintStacks(int[] stacks)
    {
        foreach (var totalSticks in stacks)
        {
            Console.Write(totalSticks + ": ");
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSticks; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" | ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Switching from arrays to generic lists is likely a good idea (though it may be an educational assignment specifically about arrays).  But you also quietly corrected the actual problem without any explanation: `for (int i = 0; i < totalSticks; i++)`

Comment: Its a school assigment and we have not started with lists yet. @David How would i get the totaltSticks? Since i declare them in the array as 5 per index. How do i convert or assign every index to a stack and then declare the amout of sticks in the stack?

Comment: @KimPersson: *"How do i convert or assign every index to a stack"* - That... doesn't sound right at all.  Why do you need to use a **stack** data structure here at all?  In your original code you are, for each element in the array, looping from `0` to the *length of the array*.  It sounds like you want to loop to the *value of the element* instead.  At best the problem is just a typo.  You want to loop from "1 to item" (or "0 to item-1"), not from "0 to the length of the array".  Now is also a great time to start using a debugger and observing the values you're using.

Comment: @David Yes, my bad.. although that wasn't actually mentioned as an issue. Have edited to clarify.

Comment: @KimPersson Have edited to hopefully give more info about the usage.

Comment: @Alfie: *"I changed the for loop from <= to <"* - You also (quietly) changed `stacks.Length` to `totalSticks`, which was the actual problem.

Comment: @David oh, right you are - I didn't even notice that when rewriting it.

Comment: @KimPersson I have added an example using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

[Alfie's answer will fix your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152403/16533015), however he's using a generic list. If you want to keep using an array of integers, all you need to is to change `array.Length` to `item` in your for-loop.
Also the `i` variable needs to start at `1` instead of `0`, otherwise it will print out 6 times instead of 5 times since you're using LTE operator in your for-loop condition.